# Giving an Exploding Kitten to another player's hand through Barking Kitten

Tags: exploding-kittens

[**Barking Kitten**](https://explodingkittens.com/how-to-play/barking-kittens) allows me to give cards of my own hand to another player's hand after they chose half of their own cards to give to me. Holding a Streaking Kitten together with an Exploding Kitten in my hand, this would allow me to give the other player an Exploding Kitten into their hand that would explode directly.

In the case that I was the one to successfully play Barking Kitten (either having both of the Barking Kittens or playing it while another player holds the second Barking Kitten card) I guess it is correct to say that the Exploding Kitten given to another player needs to explode.

**My question is** what happens if another player plays Barking Kitten(s) successfully against me while I'm holding a Streaking Kitten and an Exploding in my hand, and I give him/her my Exploding Kitten. The rules of Barking Kitten says that the player using its effect can choose which cards of the other player they want to add to their hand. Does the other player have to defuse my Exploding Kitten that he got from me, or can he directly give it back to me without adding it to his hand?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Barking Kitten FAQ](https://explodingkittens.com/how-to-play/barking-kittens) states:

> must give you half their cards (rounding up). Combine them with your hand, then choose and return the same number of cards back

Whereas [Streaking Kitten](https://explodingkittens.com/how-to-play/streaking-kittens) says:

> If another player steals or receives an Exploding Kitten from your hand, they explode. They must defuse it or lose the game.

I'd interpret this as the Exploding Kitten being received from your hand, which is anyway illegal without holding a Streaking Kitten. Therefore I'd say the receiving player must Defuse the Exploding Kitten before completing the "combine them with your hand" part and moving on as usual.